# ¿Por qué se llama «tío» al Tío de la mina?

Tags: formalidad, religión, parentesco, bolivia

[***El Tío***](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/El_T%C3%ADo_(deidad)) es una deidad demoníaca boliviana:

> Es considerado como el dios del inframundo en Cerro Rico, Potosí, y en otras regiones con tradición en extracción minera en dicho país como Oruro. Existen muchas imágenes de este espíritu en las minas de hierro. El Tío gobierna los bajos mundos, ofreciendo a los mineros protección, pero también ruina y destrucción a quienes no le hacen ofrendas.

Pero por qué se llama «[tío](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=t%C3%ADo)» a un diablo?

Answer (score 1):

Parece que representa la conexión cercana entre él y sus devotos (y posiblemente como formalidad respetuosa para no concitarle):

> [image]

- [*El culto al "tío" en las minas bolivianas*](http://www.cervantesvirtual.com/descargaPdf/el-culto-al-tio-en-las-minas-bolivianas-927224/), Gerardo Fernández